# How to use my written compiler to read files on web?

Tags: javascript, c#, compiler-construction

I'm creating a toy language that compiles to javascript.

Now that it's almost done i'm wondering how could I make the server to understand custom files (like 'myfile.mylang') and compile it with the compile i writed (in c#).

for instance, call on a webpage  and then, my compiler could be used to transform it to js.

I hope i was clear, thanks in advance for your time

Comment: That depends on the webserver. Does it run apache?

Comment: no, its written in c#

Comment: Not the compiler, the webserver. There is a program (the webserver) that maps page requests on content. An example of such webserver is *Apache*, or *Nginx*.

Comment: i want it to be used in several web sites, so it would probably be running on IIS

Comment: ASP.Net MVC controller with single action that just runs your compiler against text file and returns result maybe what you looking for... But it is very unclear from your post how much information you are looking for or whether this would even answer the question.

Comment: The situation is: I have a compiler written in c#. I want to use the language in dedicated files, and be able to reference those in my html pages just like javascript files.

Comment: It would not be likely to depend on asp.net to use it. I would like to allow ppl to use my script language in any web site written in any language.

Comment: If you incorporate the compiler code in code behind file, I don't see why not. It sounds like you read a file, process it, output a file, whether html,  javascript etc., it doesn't matter.

Comment: i was searching about other languages that compiles to js, like typescript and coffescript, it looks like they use node.js command-line tasks to compile they code to js at publihing, and there is no compilation at runtime.. no i'm looking for how to create this kind of task and if I can use my existent c# written compiler